# How to use ClientRegistration in Oauth2.0 without client secret?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have make authorization link using Spring Boot OAuth2.0 but I don't have client secret instead I have to use certificate. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

***You can use client assertion instead of a client secret.*** The client uses a certificate to prove the token request came from the client. You can use a self-signed certificate to create the client assertion

Please check this official **[document](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/10/how-to-use-postman-to-perform-a-client-credentials-grant-flow-with-a-certificate/)    and upload a certificate** as below

[image]

If the script for the document didn't work, please use the script below to create a self-assigned certificate.

```
$certroopath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"
$certname = "mycert1"
$certpassword = "P@ssw0rd1234"

$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "$certname" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certpassword -Force -AsPlainText
$certwithThumb = "cert:\CurrentUser\my\"+$cert.Thumbprint
$filepath = "$certroopath\$certname.pfx"
Export-PfxCertificate -cert $certwithThumb -FilePath $filepath -Password $pwd
```

Utilize the ClientID and TenantID that are used while the Powershell script is running. The output from the PowerShell script should be used for the client assertion parameter.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

**[Using client assertion to get access tokens from Azure AD](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/guidance/guidance-multitenant-identity-client-assertion.md)**

https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/10/how-to-use-postman-to-perform-a-client-credentials-grant-flow-with-a-certificate/